# Rails localization "lazy" lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, localization, rails-i18n

I have such views structure:

```
views
  layouts
    visitors
      _footer.html.haml
      _header.html.haml
    visitors.html.haml
```

In my `config/application.rb` I've added

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

My locales file structure looks like this:

```
config
  locales
    views
      layouts
        visitors.en.yml
```

My visitors.en.yml has such structure

```
en:
  layouts:
    visitors:
      title: Site title
```

In my `views/layouts/visitors.html.haml` I call `I18n.t('.title')`, but receive error `translation missing en.title`.

If I do like this `I18n.t('layouts.visitors.title')` - it translates everything properly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the answer. It turned out that this Rails feature works only when I call helper like this `t('.title')`. Only then the appropriate translation is picked up. If I use `I18n.t` only full `I18n.t('layouts.visitors.title')` works properly.